# Concatenated loop in java

Tags: java, loops, concatenation, httprequest, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate a few strings but this is the sample code:
The thing is after the concatenation java doenst read the new string as the given URL previous declared..this might not be hard to do but I stucked here for two hours and no answer in my research of how to do this inside one loop, anyone could help please? Thanks in advance!

```
    public HttpRequest(String query) throws IOException{

    engine0="http://google.com/search?q=";
        engine1="http://www.bing.com/search?q=";

    for(urlCountDown=2;urlCountDown!=-1;urlCountDown--){

    try {

        engineSearch=("engine"+urlCountDown);
        // Fixed search URL; drop openConnection() at the end
        url = new URL(engineSearch+URLEncoder.encode(query));
        System.out.println(url);
}
```

Comment: `engineSearch=("engine"+urlCountDown);` is NOT going to assign the value of `engine0` or `engine1` to the variable `engineSearch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
engineSearch=("engine"+urlCountDown);
```

Doesn't mean

```
engineSearch = engine1;
```

nor

```
engineSearch = engine0;
```

that's why java doesn't recognize it as a URL.

The results will be

```
engineSearch = "engine2_yourEncodedQuery_";
```

and

```
engineSearch = "engine1_yourEncodedQuery_";
```

if you want to get different strings using a loop, you have to use arrays or lists

Answer (score 5):

You should use an array to do this.

```
String engine[2];
engine[0] = "http://google.com/search?q=";
engine[1] = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=";

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    url = new URL(engineSearch+URLEncoder.encode(query));
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

Comment: What a newbie mistake, completely forgot arrays! Ty

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately most languages don't have an `eval` type function that lets you dynamically build code.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues with your code. The first time it runs, it's looking for `engine2` but that doesn't exist. Also, you are trying to access variables by concatenating them, but that won't work. When your code runs, you get `engine0+whateverisinthisvariable` rather than the value of the variable. For what youa re attempting to do, you should use an array.

Try this:

```
String[] engine = new String[2];
engine[0]="http://google.com/search?q=";
engine[1]="http://www.bing.com/search?q=";
for(urlCountDown=0;urlCountDown<2;urlCountDown++){

    try {

        engineSearch=engine[urlCountDown];
        // Fixed search URL; drop openConnection() at the end
        url = new URL(engineSearch+URLEncoder.encode(query));
        System.out.println(url);
}
```

This will loop through both of the engine elements and will get you the URL you are looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: What a newbie mistake, completely forgot arrays! Ty